# Postgresql: подстановка json-данных в IN

Tags: json, postgresql

В мою postgresql функцию приходят данные parameter в формате json

`{"name": ["Петя", "Коля", "Вася"]}`.

Есть таблица с именами, из которой надо сделать выборку класса

```
SELECT 
age, address 
FROM users 
WHERE name IN (... а вот тут как-то вставить мой входящий parameter->>'name' ...)
```

Подскажите, как это сделать синтаксически и идеологически правильно, чтобы внутри функции не устраивать ненужные предварительные парсинги строк, лишние конвертации и прочее. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно развернуть массив json в список:

```
where name in (
    select n from json_array_elements_text(parameter->'name') as n
)
```

Либо `jsonb_array_elements_text`, смотря какого типа ваш аргумент.

Есть так же возможность использовать для поиска вхождения строки в массив jsonb [штатный оператор](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```
where parameter->'name' ? name
```

Одна проблема что такая запись не использует индекс по `name`, если есть такой. В отличии от подзапроса с json_array_elements_text.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Решение оказалось действительно простым `SELECT.... IN (select value from json_array_elements_text( (parameter->>'name') ) ` ну с предварительным приведение к типу, но это уже детали. Спасибо!

Comment: обратите внимание на `->` вместо `->>`, тогда приведение типа для вызова функции не нужно.

Comment: кстати да, спасибо за корректировку!